# Runtime error '70': Permission Denied only in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this simple code that should open a CMD and execute a shell command.

```
Dim Ap As Object
Set Ap = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Ap.Run "cmd.exe /cls"
Ap.Terminate
```

The code works well in Excel-VBA but while trying to run it from a Word Document I get : `Runtime error '70': Permission Denied` at the line: `Ap.Run "cmd.exe /cls"`

I've Enabled Content for the word document , Marco Settings have been set to "Trust access to the VBA project object model". What could be the cause

Comment: What does `Ap.Terminate` do? AFAIK this method does not exist.

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: @nicomp I specified in the post, I get the error at this line `Ap.Run "cmd.exe /cls"`

Comment: @Storax I'm not quite sure, I guess it kills the created object? I got this code from someone else, the problem is that it doesn't reach  that line so it's not an issue. The line works if I run it thorough excel-vba.

Comment: You said the code works fine in Excel VBA. I doubt it does as `Terminate` does not exist. So, I think you got more code you need to show.

Comment: Fine, just remove the `Terminate` line.

Comment: Yes, of course, I already did that and tested your code in Excel and Word vba. It just works fine. WIthout more context I am afraid It will be difficult to help you.

Comment: The code as is doesn't run in Excel VBA. The only way that `Ap.terminate` wouldn't throw an error is either because `Ap` isn't the object that you say it is, or you are using something like `On Error Resume Next` to suppress the error (which is almost always a bad idea). In either case, your question is missing relevant context. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: @John: Maybe my comment was a liittle but unlcear. The code just runs fine in Excel and Word VBA without the last line `AP.Terminate`. But you are right, relevant context is missing and that's what I tried to get from the OP. It seems he is not willing or able to give it.

Comment: @Storax My comment was directed at OP rather than you. I was able to reproduce your observation that the code works no problem without that line in both Excel and Word. I was just curious why OP claimed that it worked in Excel. `On Error Resume Next` is the only thing I could think of -- but then it would leave the previous error mysterious. Perhaps it was being thrown by the VBScript interpreter rather than VBA? In any event, I am voting to close the question since they haven't adequately responded to the issues that you have raised and I have seconded.

Comment: The code had only one extra line , but I didn't want to put it because it would've been distracting. But here it is:
`Set Ap = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe /k " & "chcp 1252 &" & " im viewissue " & issue & " > " & "D:\temp_" & issue & ".txt"); Ap.Terminate;
Set Ap = Nothing;`

Comment: _The code had only one extra line , but I didn't want to put it because it would've been distracting_  Unbelievable

Comment: @Storax it makes no difference, whatever line was after that. It could be a simple Debug.Print , a full key-logger function it wouldn't have mattered if the execution stops before.

Comment: @HaR: Sorry that I was sarcastic in my previous comment. But with the code shown in your comment the `Ap.Terminate` makes sense now. Unfortunately I still can't help you as the code runs for me fine, a command box opens and after pressing enter it will be terminated like stated in the code.

Comment: It's ok, no hard feelings :) I am still investigating , found a work-around it has to do with the Word Macro security settings. I will post if I find anything relevant . Cheers !

Comment: @HaR what settings you performed ?